Format Multiple Symbols using ArcGIS Pro and Apply is greyed out
I am trying to change all of the symbology at once for a points layer. When I go to the Symbology - Primary Symbology and then click on more- format all symbols, the apply button is greyed out and I can only change the symbology individually.
What am I missing/doing wrong?
